# Fallo al construir app con apache cordova en ubuntu 16.04

Tags: cordova, webview, android

Saludos amigos, tengo un problema con `apache cordova` al construir mi aplicación. estoy usando `ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bits` he podido investigar sobre el asunto y he encontrado que hay problemas similares en esta versión de `ubuntu`, la versión de *cordova* que utilizo es **6.3.0** la herramientas necesarias para construir este tipo de aplicaciones son las siguientes y con su respectiva versión:

> versión de *nodejs* **4.2.6** 
>   versión de *apache ant* **1.9.6** 
>   *java-8-openjdk-i386*  
>   *SDK manager* rev **25.1.7**  
>   Herramientas *Android SDK tools* versión **25.1.7**  
>   *Android SDK platform-tools* versión **24.0.1** 
>   *Android SDK build-tools* **24.0.1** 
>   Android 6.0 **(API 23)** 
>   Extras *Google repository* y *Android support repository*

Variables de entorno de la "SDK" ubicación: `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android/sdk/tools
```

Al ejecutar el comando

```
:~/cordovaApp$ cordova build android
```

Como resultado recibo el fallo

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/opt/android/sdk/build-tools/24.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.157 secs
Error: /home/ricar1997/cordovaApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Alguien que tenga el mismo problema en `ubuntu 16.04` seria de gran ayuda si  pudo encontrar la solución a esta cuestión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu mensaje de error es:

> aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Ahora que leo detenidamente tu pregunta veo que usas

> ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bits
> y
> Android SDK build-tools 24.0.1

En Android Studio he tenido el mismo problema con build-tools 24.0.1 he tenido que cambiar la configuración en `build.gradle` a versión 23.0.3, configura una versión de Build-tools y platform-tools a una versión antes de 24.0.1 por ejemplo 23.0.1 o 21.0.3 (me parece es la anterior).

y prueba nuevamente, comenta resultados.

#### Actualización:

Este problema como podemos deducir se presenta al cambiar a Android SDK build-tools 24.0+, es generado porque esta versión requiere Java 8.0. Si no contamos con esta versión de Java se presenta este problema, sin duda en un futuro no lejano requeriremos de actualizar.

De hecho hasta el día de hoy 12 August 2016 no esta registrada la versión 24.0+ en la página de [liberaciones SDK Build Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html#notes), la última es

> Build Tools, Revision 23.0.3 (March 2016)

Comment: Gracias Elenasys por haber comentado sobre el fallo en la herramienta de construcción que ocasionaba el fallo, en nuestro caso tuvimos que eliminar esa versión e instalar una anterior y listo!

Comment: Que bien @RicardoMoreno me da gusto se solucionara el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hace menos de un mes yo coloque una pregunta que se refería a exactamente lo mismo que esta pregunta, pero nadie me contesto, muchas gracias Elenasys yo tenia el mismo problema y pude resolver gracias a tu respuesta, en mi caso también uso cordova y no se usar mucho gradle, así que no se como configurarlo, busque en el archivo build.gradle como dijiste y no aparece muy claro cual es la versión del build-tools que en realidad utiliza gradle o al menos yo no pude definir cual era la versión en ese archivo, pero en ese archivo si dice en comentarios que se usara una versión de build-tools superior a la `19.x.x`, incluso en la documentacion de la pagina web de cordova tambien dice lo mismo, así que la solución que conseguí fue desintalar del `sdk-android` las versiones `24.x.x` y instalar la `23.0.3` que es la versión inmediata inferior de build-tools y esa fue la solución a el problema, ahora cuando compilo con `cordova build android` todo va de maravilla. Así que tocayo Ricardo Moreno, intenta lo que yo hice a ver si te funciona! Saludos!

Comment: que tal amigo, pues si era la solución instale android SDK build-tools 23.0.3 y he removido la versión que daba el fallo y ahora no hay problema alguno!

Comment: Hola Amigos Ricardos me alegra que hayan solucionado el problema, como comentaba esto aplica para Cordoba y  también para Android Studio, aregaré más detalles sobre este problema en mi respuesta...

Comment: Hola Ricardo bienvenido a SOes, acabo de revisar tu perfil y solamente aparece esta pregunta. Agradecería que compartas el enlace de la otra pregunta para cerrarla por estar duplicada de acuerdo a lo que mencionas, enlazando a la respuesta de @Elenasys

Comment: @Elenasys coloco en mi pregunta el enlace a la respuesta, aquí les dejo el enlace a mi pregunta, la cual queda resuelta [http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18354/6353]